# fixed div overlapping adjacent div on horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I am building a template which has a fixed header and a fixed side bar on the left. My issue is that when I shorten the window and scroll horizontally, the fixed div overlaps the adjacent *'.content'*.

I don't want the fixed *'.sidebar1'* to overlap *'.content'* div when I scroll horizontally. How do I fix this?

```css
html,body
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.header
{
 width:100%;
 height:46px;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 background:blue;
}

.page_wrap
{
 width:1040px;
 display:block;
 margin:70px auto 0;
 background:purple;
}

.content
{
 width:500px;
 height:1060px;
 display:inline-block;
 background:red;
 color:white;
 margin:5px;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin-left:270px;
}

.sidebar1
{
 display:inline-block;
 width:250px;
 height:500px;
 position:fixed;
 top:70px;
 background:pink;
 margin:5px;
 vertical-align:top;
}


.sidebar2
{
 display:inline-block;
 width:250px;
 background:pink;
 margin:5px;
 vertical-align:top;
}

.footer
{
 width:1040px;
 height:50px;
 margin: 20px auto 0;
 text-align:center;
 background:magenta;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Temp</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="temp.css">
 </head> 
 
 <body>
  
  <div class="header">
   Header Content
  </div>
  
  <div class="page_wrap">
   
     <div class="sidebar1">
      sidebar 1
      <div class="test"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="content">
      Article Content
     </div>
     
     <div class="sidebar2">
      sidebar 2
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that fixed technically makes it take up no space on the page.

I noticed you have fixed width and height on your content, which is probably your first problem. Fixed width on large containers is typically a bad idea, as it breaks everything else on your page, or prevents it from displaying the way you want.

The end result should look something like:

.content{

<s>`width:500px;
height:1060px;`</s>

```
margin-left:270px;
display:inline-block;
background:red;
color:white;
margin:5px;
vertical-align:top;

    }
```

If you need it to scroll horizontally for some reason, then I would say set `position:fixed;` on the `div.content` and add a property to your HTML `wrap="off"` and see if that does what you want it to.

Hopefully this helped. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your input. While it did not completely solve my problem, it did give me a few ideas that could possibly work with.

Comment: No problem! Glad I helped at least somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question

Check https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/47p6r6hq/

```
<header>Header</header>
<aside>Side</aside>
<section>

   <div class="wide">
      My Wide Content
   </div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
header {
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   background: red;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
}

aside {
   top: 30px;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 300px;
   background: blue;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
}

section {
   top: 30px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 300px;
   right: 0;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: fixed;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}

.wide {
   color: #000;
   width: 1500px;
   background: yellow;
   height: 50px;
}
```